# Accessing parameters in other models - OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a parameter under section protected that is needed for further calculations:

```
parameter Integer Ns = integer(ceil(L / dx))
```

It shouldn't be modified that's why I placed it there.
However, I want to access this parameter while building my general model. Particularly to access it in the other component that I could do something like:

```
Ns = componentName.Ns
```

But as it is under protected section it is not possible. I did a work around by simply adding another parameter in general section:

```
parameter Integer N=Ns
```

However, this parameter appears in the GUI and can be modified, which I would like to avoid by all means.

Is there any solution for this? I hope it is clear what I mean.

Comment: If you want it to be visible and accessible, but no longer changeable, then you should mark it `final`. https://mbe.modelica.university/components/subsystems/propagation/

Comment: @matth I am aware of `final`, though how do I make it for the `Integer`? Particularly in this line `parameter Integer Ns = integer(ceil(L / dx))`

Comment: What about `final parameter Integer Ns = integer(ceil(L / dx))` ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Converting my comments into an answer:
If you want a parameter to be visible and accessible from outside of the model class, but no longer changeable, then you should mark it final, like this:

```
final parameter Integer Ns = integer(ceil(L / dx))
```

As you can see in the example, the parameter can be calculated and becomes final afterwards.